# QTabWidget inside a QSplitter switching very slow

Tags: qt

I'm new to Qt, and wanted to implement some dialogs for a program.

The GUI of the dialog is simple: there's a tree on the left, and some tabs on the right (the number of tabs may change), and there are some widgets for input in each tab.

But when I implemented this dialog with Qt5.0.2, I found it is very slow when I switch tabs. (usually more than 0.1s to switch a tab, sometimes it stopped to response for several seconds if I randomly click on the tabs for many times)

I'm wondering if I was using Qt in a wrong way, or if there is something I can do to improve the performance

Here is an example for my scenario:

```
    TestQT::TestQT(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    QSplitter* pSplitter = new QSplitter();
    QTreeWidget* pTree = new QTreeWidget();

    pSplitter->addWidget(pTree);

    QTabWidget* pTabs = new QTabWidget();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        QWidget* pPage = new QWidget();
        QVBoxLayout* pLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            QHBoxLayout* pLineLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
            pLineLayout->addWidget(new QCheckBox());
            pLineLayout->addWidget(new QLineEdit());
            pLayout->addLayout(pLineLayout);
        }
        pPage->setLayout(pLayout);

        pTabs->addTab(pPage, tr("Page%1").arg(i));
    }

    pSplitter->addWidget(pTabs);

    this->setCentralWidget(pSplitter);
}
```

Comment: Works fast for me. Try to run the code under profiler to see what slows down the program.

Comment: Hello Riateche, could you please suggest a profiling tool for QT on Windows platform? Thanks!

Comment: If you use MinGW compiler, `gprof` is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MSVC 11, is there any suggestions for that?

Comment: Visual Studio profiler then.

Comment: Ping? Did running it under a profiler help you find the problem?

Comment: You can try very sleepy for profiling as well. Be sure you are not debugging.

Comment: Is this the entire code? I bet it isn't, and your problem is elsewhere. You're likely blocking the GUI thread.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Kuba. Mostly GUI malfunctions are occurred when another action is blocking the thread it is running on, so your solution in these cases is to either move the GUI or that action to another thread.

Since I only see the code for GUI here, let's try moving the GUI to another thread first. With the header `QThread`, add these codes to your function and see if it helps:

```
QThread * t1 = new QThread();
this->moveToThread(t1);
t1->start();
```